# warning message "kex protocol error: type 7" during scp, rsync or shell work

Tags: linux, rsync, openssh, scp

Lately, I get lots of these errors on my home server.
Their occurrence seems proportional to the traffic, so if I am working in a shell on the server I may seem 1-2 a day. But If I start some rsync, or scp process I see 5-6 per file transferred.

```
kex protocol error: type 7 seq 358115
kex protocol error: type 7 seq 429489
kex protocol error: type 7 seq 500711
kex protocol error: type 7 seq 571534
kex protocol error: type 7 seq 642352
```

The server is a Gentoo Linux running **OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h**
This problem seems to happen independent on the client that is connected to the server. That might be my notebook (also Gentoo with **OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h**) or a Qnap NAS (Linux QNAP1 3.4.6 #1 SMP Wed Jun 1 05:17:33 CST 2016 x86_64 unknown -  **OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1t**)

I have not been able to find out what a "type 7" error means. Despite these warnings the transfer seems to work well, I have checked the transferred files and there is no coruption. So basically these warning messages just garble the screen output, which is my main motivation to get rid of them.

Comment: From this log is not clear why the error occurred, but it is certainly inside of [openssh](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/kex.c#L323). If you can reproduce this behaviour, can you provide the verbose log from the client (`scp -vvv original_argumetns`)? It should say what message caused this error. The message means that the server received message, that is not supported.

Comment: I can actually reproduce it for over a year now and across distributions (former Gentoo, now Arch). Meanwhile this is still a thing with OpenSSH 7.4 on Arch copying to a LibreElec as well as  to a Qnap NAS.

Comment: Almost a year ago I asked for the verbose log to see the context of the message.

Comment: @Jakuje verbose log is here https://pastebin.com/HgGAtH9R

Answer (score 7):

Seems to be a bug in openssh :

http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2016-August/035350.html

To avoid Problems try to use in your sshd_config:

UsePrivilegeSeparation yes